# What is the correct 4.5*3.0mm DC connector for Asus Vivobook Pro 16X?

Tags: laptop, power, asus-laptop, connector

I'm trying to find the correct DC plug adapter for my Asus Vivobook Pro 16X. According to [this non-official site](https://emerpower.com/products/genuine-120w-asus-charger-for-asus-vivobook-pro-16x-oled-m7600-m7600q-20v-6a-ac-adapter-power-supply) it uses the 4.5 * 3.0mm DC plug; I have physically measured the OEM charger plug on my computer, and it is indeed 4.5 * 3.0mm.

I found [various sizes of DC plug adapters online](https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07SMFD1QR) like the "4.5 * 3.0mm **HP**" and the "4.5 * 3.0mm **Dell**", but no  4.5 * 3.0mm **Asus** unfortunately.

1. What is the difference between "4.5 * 3.0mm **HP**" and "4.5 * 3.0mm **Dell**"?
2. Which of the two, if any, is closer to the Asus 4.5*3.0mm plug?

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B07SMFD1QR contains multiple adapters. Which is the correct adapter for Asus Vivobook Pro 16X?